# Right usage of MongoDB update functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, updates

I have a probably simple problem using the MongoDB API for updating a document. I have tried several things but nothing was successful. Inserting and deleting in contrast work fine.

So what am I doing. I'm trying to update an existing document with the following approaches:

```
router.post('/updatecontact', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.id);
    console.log(req.body.data);
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('contacts');
    collection.update( { '_id': req.body.id }, req.body.data, true );
});
```

Console output gives me:

```
5666adefcd80a0f3bdbdebe1
{"_id":"5666adefcd80a0f3bdbdebe1","surname":"Test","firstname":"-","group":"-","organization":[{"type":"Verwaltung","name":"Test-Orga","orgunit":""}],"position":"-"}
```

so both parameters seem to be okay but the server returns only:

```
POST /contacts/updatecontact 500 43.911 ms - 1548
```

The same happens with the replaceOne function

```
router.post('/updatecontact', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.id);
    console.log(req.body.data);
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('contacts');
    collection.replaceOne(
        {'_id': req.body.id},
        JSON.parse(req.body.data), 
        {upsert: true},
        function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});
```

Whether or not I do a `JSON.parse()` or use another filter.

e.g. `{'surname': JSON.parse(req.body.data).surname`} the result doesn't change.

What's working in contrast is the following insert function where the relevant parts seem to be the same.

```
router.post('/insert', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('contacts');
    collection.insert(JSON.parse(req.body.data), function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
        console.log('ID is ' + result._id);
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { oid: result._id } : { oid: '' }
        );
    });
});
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong?

Comment: Try using `ObjectId(req.body.id)`

Answer (score 0):

I used to doing the update using the `save` method (req.collection.save). I've a `middelware` that adds the collection returned by `findById` to `req`.

```
var middelware = function(req, res, next){
    yourCollection.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
        if(err)
            res.status(500).send(err);
        else if(data){
            req.data= data;
            next();
        }else{
            res.status(404).send('no data found');
        }
    });
}

//this will update parts of your existing resource
var put = function(req, res){
    req.data.a= req.body.a;
    req.data.b= req.body.b;
    ...
    req.data.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
            res.status(500).send(error);
        else
            res.json(req.data);
    }); 
}

var router = express.Router();
router.use('/:id',middelware);
router.route('/')
.put(put);
```